# Watching a C++ array in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I have declared an array as follows:

```
int *arr;
```

Is there any way in visual studio to watch all the elements of the array while debugging, rather than having to manually place watch for an element *(arr+1), *(arr+2) and so on.

Comment: That is a pointer to int not an array!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If `arr` is a pointer to an array of ten integers, you can add "`arr,10`" to the watch window and when you expand it it will show the ten elements [obviously, you can replace the `10` with whatever the length of your array is].

Comment: precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do a memory window on that address - will show all the contents.